# How do I only show half of my div?

Tags: html, css

I've got a button with `100px` height, `100px` width and a border radius of `100px`. This makes a 360 degree circle, but I only want to hide half of it. I've searched for everything but I can't find it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a parent div, add `overflow: hidden;` and `position: relative;` to it. In the child div, do `position: relative;` and `top: -50px;`

Answer (score 6):

By "hide half of it", what do you mean?

Do you want a semicircle?

```
width:100px;
height:50px;
border-radius:50px 50px 0 0;
```

Or something else? Please elaborate further and I can provide more options ;)

Comment: Thanks :) I want to hide half of the circle before clicking it, after that I want to scroll down the page using jQuery and when scrolling up it would be nice to see just a whole circle

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in another div with `height: 50px` and `overflow:hidden`. That should do the trick.